Unable to display loading component in Next.js 13 using loading.jsx file
so as the title says I have my loading.jsx file and when I shift from home page to about page then neither do I see the loading spinner in either of them. Can anyone help me with this?
loading.jsx - file
import { Loader } from 'lucide-react'


const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-content items-center min-h-screen'>
        <Loader className="animate-spin" size = {150} color="rgba(0,136,202,0.75)"/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Loading

page.jsx - file
import React from 'react'

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <div >
      <h1>Hello There!!</h1>

    </div>
  );
}


both the files are in app directory
I am using next.js 13.5.1
Sometimes I get this warning during compiling
-Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.

Trying wrapping your Home() in <Suspense fallback={<Loading />} I am not fully sure it will work in nextjs. But overall what you are looking for is a suspense loading and a fallback component (loading spinner) while the main component loads
